# Simple math addition

Tags: python, math

so I just want to do some simple math addition
get number from the first file ( let's say it's 1)
and number from the second file ( let's say it's 2)
so what I'm getting is 12, not 3
I would really appreciate the help.

```
myfile = open('file.txt', "r")
onecaracter = myfile.read(2)
with open('liczba1.txt', 'w') as f:
print(onecaracter, file=f)

myfile = open('file.txt', "r")
twocaracter = myfile.read(myfile.seek(4))

with open('liczba22.txt', 'w') as f:
print(twocaracter, file=f)

with open('liczba1.txt', "r") as file:
z = file.read(1)

with open('liczba22.txt', "r") as fil:
b = fil.read(1)

print(z + b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `z` and `b` are likely `str` types, and the `+` operator is defined on `str` types as concatenation. You can cast the two variables as integers and they should add as you expect, i.e.:

```
print(int(z) + int(b))
```

To illustrate this, you can always print out the type of a variable:

```
print(type(z))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myfile = open('file.txt', "r")
onecaracter = myfile.read(2)
with open('liczba1.txt', 'w') as f:
print(onecaracter, file=f)

myfile = open('file.txt', "r")
twocaracter = myfile.read(myfile.seek(4))

with open('liczba22.txt', 'w') as f:
print(twocaracter, file=f)

with open('liczba1.txt', "r") as file:
z = file.read(1)

with open('liczba22.txt', "r") as fil:
b = fil.read(1)

print(int(z) + int(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do a type cast:

```
total = int(z) + int(b)
print(total)
```